# Ext js button in a toolbar

Tags: extjs

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to only show a button in the toolbar whenever a if statement is true.

for my case i have a snippet here

```
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Pay!',
                    handler: function() {
                        console.log('haha');
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

a toolbar that has a button

but i only want to show the button pay whenever the grid is not empty(I also have a grid)

how is this possible.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to all events that indicate changes of the row count. Most of them are store events:

```
xtype:'grid',
tbar:[{
  xtype:'button',
  itemId:'Test'
}],
buttonchange:function() {
  this.down('button[itemId=Test]').setVisible(this.getStore().getCount()>0);
},
listeners:{
  viewready:function(gridview) {
    var grid = gridview.ownerCt;
    grid.buttonchange();
    store.on({
      load: grid.buttonchange(),
      add: grid.buttonchange(),
      remove: grid.buttonchange(),
      clear: grid.buttonchange(),
      filterchange: grid.buttonchange(),
      scope: grid
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your grid data handled by a store you have to add store load event listener.

I create [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13vo) for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExtJs5/6+ you might be able to bind the visibility of your button to the store count.

Something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Pay!',
            bind: {
                hidden: '{!storeCount}'
            }
            handler: function() {
                console.log('haha');
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And you need to set the storeCount yourself as the property is not accessible directly (see https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286770-unable-to-bind-view-to-store-size)

Assuming you have *yourStore* declared in your **ViewModel**, in the **ViewController** you should be able to do

```
initViewModel: function(viewModel) {
    viewModel.bind('{yourStore}', function(store) {
        if(store) {
            store.on('datachanged', function () {
                this.set('storeCount', this.getCount()) // this is the viewModel as I set the scope of the function
            });
        }
    }, viewModel);
}
```